# Throw error when attempting to access non-existent property

Tags: javascript

I have an object like:

```
const foo = {
  bar: 'bar'
};
```

I would like to modify it such that if someone tried to access a non-existent property an error would be thrown rather than returning undefined.

For example,

```
const baz = foo.baz;
// Error: Property 'baz' does not exist on object 'foo'
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With ECMAScript 6 you can use proxies.

```
var original = {"foo": "bar"};
var proxy = new Proxy(original, {
    get: function(target, name, receiver) {
        console.log("Name of requested property: " + name);
        var rv = target[name];
        if (rv === undefined) {
          console.log("There is no such thing as " + name + ".")
          rv = "Whatever you like"
        }
        return rv;
    }
});

console.log("original.foo = " + proxy.foo);     // "bar"
console.log("proxy.foo = " + proxy.whatever);   // "Whatever you like"
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5b3wx9w/

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.

Comment: Note that this will also log an error, when the property *does* exist, but is set to `undefined`. You can instead use `target.hasOwnProperty(name)` or `(name in target)`, depending on whether you want disregard or respect inherited properties, respectively.